# How to replace an item with another item by ID in Treelist field using Powershell?

Tags: powershell-extensions, tree-list

I want to replace an item with another item in a Treelist. Basically, the items I want to replace are broken links. Suppose,

There are two items A and B. A is used in a Treelist field, so I want to replace item A with item B in Treelist by using their ID.

Please let me know the optimal solution. Thanks.

Comment: I think that you should be able to find almost ready-to-use snippet with google serach. Saerch for **replace field value sitecore powershell** First result that appear for me: https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2016/05/25/sitecore-powershell-update-field-values/
The difference is that William replace url, you will have to adjust it to replace item id.

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak is it possible to replace broken links in treelist with other items?

Comment: There is Sitecore admin page that allows removing broken links (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28738468/6149877). But from what I see you need to replace it with other value, am I right? If you just need to get rid of them, follow the link.

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak I know to remove broken links I can use Sitecore tool, but I have to replace the broken links with other items. I have 4 items[broken] which are selected in more than 100 items in treelist's field. So, here I just want to replace the id of these 4 items in every treelist.

Comment: Try the link from first comment then. You will have to edit raw values of an item (https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2017/02/how-to-view-raw-values-in-sitecore-cms/). Links to items are represented in Sitecore as GUIDs (https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier). Once you know GUID you are looking for you can find items and then replace field value.

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak I know the GUID of all the items which are going to be replaced by new items. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something similar to what I have here with pse and adapt it with your use case if needed. And basically, broken link usually (if not all the time, not quite sure) use {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} value for the item id. So I play around that to fix my links. I consider this more of a quick fix so at least you don't have to manually fix them all at once but instead fix with a generic item fast, then apply manual fix on item where and when needed...

```
$rootPath = 'master:/sitecore/path/to/your/parentFolder';
$templateId = '{FFB1DA32-2764-47DB-83B0-95B843546A7E}';

$invalidItemLinkValue = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}';

$validGenericLinkItemValue = '<link id="{8AD423E4-5EA3-4C8C-ADC9-45CDB869BCE1}" querystring="" text="" title="" class="" linktype="internal" />'
$validGenericItem = '{F4D50806-6B89-4F2D-89FE-F77FC0A07D48}';

Set-Location $rootPath;

Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.TemplateId -eq $templateId) 
    {
        $treeListField = $_.Fields["YourTreeListField"].Value;
        if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($treeListField))
        {
            $itemsGuidFromYourTreeListField = $treeListField.Split('|').Trim();
            if($itemsGuidFromYourTreeListField -ne $null)
            {
                foreach($itemGuid in $itemsGuidFromYourTreeListField)
                {
                    # ref : https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/provider/get-item
                    $currentItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $itemGuid -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
                    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($currentItem.Fields["LinkField"].Value) -or $currentItem.Fields["LinkField"].Value -like $invalidItemLinkValue)
                    {   
                        # ref : https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items
                        # if you want to update the actual link reference with a general link...
                        $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                        $currentItem.Fields["LinkField"].Value = $validGenericLinkItemValue;
                        $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null;

                        # a) if you want to remove the reference from the treelist and use a new "generic" item that is hardcoded here...
                        $treeListField = $treeListField.Replace($itemGuid, $validGenericItem);
                    }
                }

                # b) if you want to update the actual link reference with a general link...
                $_.Editing.BeginEdit();
                $_.Fields["YourTreeListField"].Value = $itemsGuidFromYourTreeListField;
                $_.Editing.EndEdit() | Out-Null;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below should help you.

Modify the variables as required. You may have to run the script a few times, changing the values as required.

```
function ToArray {
    Begin { $output = @(); }
    Process { $output += $_; }
    End { return , $output; }
}
$ParentItemId = "<Add Id of the Parent Item>"
$Language = "en"
$TemplateName = "<Add Template Name of the item to be filtered>"
$FieldName = "<Add Field Name of the Treelist field>"
$OldFieldValue = "<Add Broken Link Item ID Value>"
$NewFieldValue = "<Add Item Id Value to be replaced with>"

$AllItems = Get-ChildItem $ParentItemId -Language $Language -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq $TemplateName } | ToArray

foreach($i in $AllItems)
{
    $oldValue = $i.Fields[$FieldName].Value
    if($oldValue -Match $OldFieldValue)
    {
        $i.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $i["FieldName"] = $oldValue -Replace $OldFieldValue, $NewFieldValue
        $i.Editing.EndEdit()
    }
}
```